# Word2vecの追加学習について

Tags: python, c, アルゴリズム, 自然言語処理, word2vec

Word2Vecの追加学習について質問します。

あるコーパスを一度学習し、ベクトルを生成した後、そのコーパスに未知語を追加したら、未知語のベクトル化をするためにはゼロからコーパスを再学習する必要があるのでしょうか？
（要するにコーパスを継ぎ足して繰り返し学習したいです）

西尾泰和さんの、『word2vec による自然言語処理』によると、ネガティブサンプリングは「コーパスを継ぎ足して繰り返し学習する場合には有用」とありますが、どのようにコマンドを指定すれば、学習結果を利用して未知語に対応するような学習ができるのでしょうか？

`-negative` オプションの引数は `<int>` のみですし、未知語の抽出には `-read-vocab <file>` オプションを使えるかなとは思いましたが、学習結果を利用するオプションはないですよね？

どなたかご教示いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 2):

gensimの場合なら以下のようにして古いモデルを読み込んだ後に新しいデータを与えれば学習できるはずですよ。

```py
model = word2vec.Word2Vec.load("old_model")
model.train(sentences)
```